# How come my filtered search bar results are out of scope when text is empty?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I was using the following tutorial to let my users search for "locations" and in turn the table view will filter the results based on the search text. I even added "scopes" so the user can filter between stuff like "All" and "Food". This works great. However the problem is that say it is on the Food scope tab below the search bar and the search bar text is empty, it will default back to showing All results even though I just want it to show all of the Food results, not all of the All results. The same problem happens for the other scopes (Bus and Parking). When I start typing it works though (will grab results from just Food scope). How can I show all of the Food scope results only when text is empty instead of what is currently happening (showing all of All scope even though I am on the Food scape tab)?

[Ray Weinerlich Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial)

Here are the relevant parts of my code...

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Food", "Bus", "Parking"]
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            return filteredLocations.count
        }
        return locations.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("campusLocationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CampusLocationTableViewCell {

            let location: Location
            if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                location = filteredLocations[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                location = locations[indexPath.row]
            }

            cell.configureCampusLocationCell(location.locationName, locationLatitude: location.locationLatitude, locationLongitude: location.locationLongitude)

            return cell
        } else {
            return CampusLocationTableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredLocations = locations.filter({( location : Location) -> Bool in
            let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (location.locationCategory == scope)
            return categoryMatch && location.locationName.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Extensions...

```
extension CampusLocationsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}

extension CampusLocationsViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not really hard, just tweak your `filterContentForSearchText ` a little, compare the other scope first then only compare the `All` scope then it will show correctly

Comment: I wish I knew how to :P I will try. Tried earlier and nothing happened.

Comment: try remove `(scope == "All") ||`

Comment: That is what I had originally tried but it made no difference whatsoever =/

Comment: try to check the `searchText` is empty string then only `return categoryMatch` since it will be always fail if `searchText` is empty string

Comment: is that while still removing (scope == "All") || from categoryMatch?

Comment: try both with and without and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121220/discussion-between-tj3n-and-jason-fel).